# How to get a subway station geocode in Android

Tags: android, geocoding

I want to get the latitude and longitude of a subway/tramway station from its name (for example: Powell St. in San Francisco).

Could you please tell me how can I do this in Android (using Google maps or another service)?

Comment: did you try to look for a solution through Google?  this is extremely easy though Google Places API

Answer (score 0):

Never used [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/), but i know they can convert lat&long to some place (for example: Powell St. in San Francisco).

So i guess they have something that goes the other way around.